# Cast Eigen::MatrixXd to Eigen::MatrixXf

Tags: c++

I am using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) on a C++ program.

I wonder if there is a way to cast from `Eigen::MatrixXd` to `Eigen::MatrixXf`.
`static_cast <Eigen::MatrixXf>` doesn't seem to work and neither `A.cast<MatrixXf>` (this is the cast method from Eigen).

Any solution for this type of cast?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd d;                       // Matrix of doubles.
Eigen::MatrixXf f = d.cast <float> ();   // Matrix of floats.
```

Comment: I made a confusion in my description since I am trying to cast MatrixXd to MatrixXf (and not has I described first). Following your sugestion I've used .cast<float>() and it did the trick. (I was missing the () in the end.)