# Eigen c++ casting

Tags: c++, matrix, casting, eigen

I'm having trouble multiplying two matrices using the Eigen library. I have the following function. Here is a small example of what I would like to do :

Program name: testMatOp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;

template <typename DerivedA, typename DerivedB>
void multiply(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedA> &A,
               const Eigen::ArrayBase<DerivedB> &B){
  Eigen::MatrixXf C(2,4);
  C.array() = A.array().rowwise() * B.cast<float>();
}

int main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXf A(2,4);
  Eigen::MatrixXf C(2,4);
  //igen::VectorXf v(4);
  Eigen::Array<int,1,Eigen::Dynamic>B;
  B.resize(4);

  A << 1, 2, 6, 9,
         3, 1, 7, 2;

  B << 0,
       1,
       0,
       0;

  multiply(A,B);
}
```

I would like to pass Matrix A and Vector B to multiply. I understand that Eigen does not do automatic promotion and that B needs to be casted as a float vector in order for the multiplication to happen. When I compile, I get the following compilation error among others

```
testMatOp.cpp:34:44: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
testMatOp.cpp:34:44: error: expected ';' before 'float'
testMatOp.cpp: In instantiation of 'void multiply(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&, const Eigen::ArrayBase<DerivedB>&) [with DerivedA = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>; DerivedB = Eigen::Array<int, 1, -1>]':
testMatOp.cpp:54:15:   required from here
testMatOp.cpp:34:3: error: no match for 'operator*' in '((const Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> > >*)(&(& A)->Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::array<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >()))->Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::rowwise<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> > >() * B.Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>::cast<NewType>'
testMatOp.cpp:34:3: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../3rdparty/Eigen/Core:336:0,
                 from ../3rdparty/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from testMatOp.cpp:26:
```

What might I be doing wrong. I did take a look at this post :
[Cast Eigen::MatrixXd to Eigen::MatrixXf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764031/cast-eigenmatrixxd-to-eigenmatrixxf) 
which correctly describes how to cast, but I'm unable to make it work for this example.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

-a

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `cast()` is a template member function, in template code you have to prefix it with the `template` keyword:

```
B.template cast<float>();
```

Comment: [C++ keywords: template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template)> Inside a template definition, `template` can be used to declare that a dependent name is a template.

Answer (score 4):

`B` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).  To access its template member `cast`, you have to write

```
B.template cast
```

C++ is context-sensitive. When encountering a `<`, it tries to figure out if it is `operator<` or angle bracket.

```
// std::vector is a template, so < is an angle bracket
std::vector < float >

// 3 is not a template, so < is operator<
3 < 5
```

However, the type of `B` is `const Eigen::ArrayBase<DerivedB>&`, which depends on the template parameter `DerivedB`. C++ cannot decide if `B.cast` is a template. When this happens, C++ always guess that it is not a template and interprets the following `<` as `operator<`.

Why C++ is so *stupid* that it cannot recognize previously declared template `ArrayBase::cast`? Well, someone may specialize `ArrayBase<int>`.

```
template<>
class ArrayBase<int>
{
  public:
    int cast = 3;
};
```

Therefore one cannot deduce that `B.cast` is a template.